# Add field with drupal ajax and select list

Tags: ajax, drupal

I want update the message in the textarea according to the selected option, do you know how I can do something like that ?

Select list : field_level_list with options : Ticket level 1 / Ticket level 2 / Ticket level 3

This is the Hook form_alter :

```
function custom_support_form_support_ticket_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    $form['field_level_list']['und']['#ajax'] = [
        'event'    => 'change',
        'callback' => 'custom_support_ticket_ajax_form_callback',
        'wrapper'  => 'level_message',
        'effect'   => 'slide'
    ];

    $form['field_level_list']['und']['#weight'] = -2;
    $form['field_level_list']['und']['#suffix'] = '<div id="level_message"></div>';
}
```

This is the callback function :

```
function custom_support_ticket_ajax_form_callback($args)
{
    $cas = $args['field_level_list']['und']['#value'];

    switch($cas){
        case 1:
            $message = t('Ticket 1');
            break;
        case 2: 
            $message = t('Ticket 2');
            break;
        case 3:
            $message = t('Ticket 3');
            break;
        default :
            $message = 'X';
    }

    $form['level_message']['level_textarea'] = [
        '#type'  => 'textarea',
        '#title' => 'message',
        '#value' => $message,
        '#weight' => -9,
    ];

    $form['level_message']['level_submit'] = [
        '#type'  => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Send',
        '#ajax'  => [
            'event'    => 'click',
            'callback' => 'custom_support_sendMessage_callback'
        ],
        '#weight' => -8
    ];


    return ajax_command_replace('#level_message', $form['level_message']);}
```

That works but I get always the same message ($message). If I click first on 'Ticket level 1' I get 'Ticket 1' in textarea field, but after if I change to 'Ticket level 2' the message 'Ticket 2' does not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not the best way but it's working :

```
$form['#prefix'] = '<div id="level_message">';
$form['#suffix'] = '</div>';
```